# IHttpHandler and continue to page with PageParser.GetCompiledPageInstance

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler, ihttphandler

I am trying to do a simple HttpHandler that checks some things (security - though this is unimportant) and continue on to the page. It should be simple, but I obviously have 1 or both parameters to GetCompiledPageInstance incorrect:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    if (CheckAccess(context))
        PageParser.GetCompiledPageInstance(context.Request.Path, context.Request.PhysicalPath, context);
}

public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }

private bool CheckAccess(HttpContext context)
{
    return true;
}
```

This is a website, not application, though I don't think that makes a difference.

When I add the handler code to the web config

```
<add name="SecurityHandler" verb="*" path="*.aspx" type="SecurityHandler" />
```

Now I get an error that I did not get prior to adding it (no other changes):

> Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration file or in the Page directive. Please also make sure that System.Web.SessionStateModule or a custom session state module is included in the \\ section in the application configuration.

Never mind. Found the answer to this 2nd part: [Problem with HttpHandler and session state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637189/problem-with-httphandler-and-session-state)

implement IRequiresSessionState in the handler

Comment: I believe the second parameter in the GetCompiledPageInstance needs to be just the file name and not the filename AND path. Try using  System.IO.Path.GetFileName(context.Request.PhysicalPath);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
    PageParser.GetCompiledPageInstance(context.Request.Path, context.Request.PhysicalPath, context )
         .ProcessRequest( context );
```