# Obfuscate HTTP Handler designed to return image

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, webforms

I'm trying to retrieve an image from a HTTP Handler.

An issue which I'm having is trying to make it so that only the application can access the image, I've tried editing the anonymous IIS authentication to allow the application pool identity but this still lets users through.

Here's an example:

1. ASPX page makes a call to the handler (picService.ashx?id=1) passing in an ID via query string
2. HTTP Handler sends back image
3. The image source is Services/picService.ashx?id=1

This all works fine. Now if a user wanted to go and visit picService.ashx and type in any old ID, it would return the image which correlates to that ID. I'm working with sensitive information so this isn't acceptable.

I've had a look at HTTP Forbidden handlers but I'm not sure whether I'm going down the right route.

I've also tried returning the image in the ASPX page but you can't do this due to the Image control needing a URL.

How can I return an image from a database and have the source of the image be secure?

Should I be doing this a different way? Or am I on the right track (http forbidden)?

Comment: Clients should not be able to directly access the service and retrieve images. This question is about the many ways of achieving this.

Comment: Why do you need to settle for obfuscation instead of enforcing proper security?

Comment: Proper security being? Users are authorised to use the resource(as they need to retrieve images), but the issue is calling the web service. See my comment to Devesh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A technique I have used in the past is to have the page (step 1) create a GUID, and register a cache item keyed by the GUID that has the actual image URL in the object. The page constructs the url for the handler, using the GUID and passes to the handler

The handler (step 2) then knows to go to cache to get the actual value and return the content.

This way you only expose the temporary "magic" value. Its definitely obfuscation and not a substitute for proper security.

As an example (from memory, syntax may be off a bit)

In the aspx or caller

```
    string keyValue = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    int yourImageID = 5;

    Cache.Add(keyValue, yourImageID) //expire in 5 or 10 seconds
    string url = "Handler.ashx?imgID=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(keyValue);
    Response.Redirect(url, false);
```

In your handler (I use ashx mostly, choose whatever suits your need)

```
 string key = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(context.Request.QueryString.Get("imgID"));

 int yourImageID = (int) context.Cache.Get(key);

 //get your image from the db and return the content
```

Again, just because I used a guid doesn't mean you have to, but if you are trying to obfuscate the IDentity, then choose something that does not correlate to the IDentity.

Comment: Any chance you could give an example of this? (I have no idea I'm afraid)

I was thinking of using one-way hashing the ID (Ids are sequentially generated 8 digit values), storing this in a table and then looking up for the real value, but this wouldn't be secure either if the client knew what was being queried on, as all users know what their ID is & the obvious database overhead.

Comment: This works fine. Thanks for all the help, marking as answer as although Thymine suggested the same thing, you were first & a decent example.

Answer (score 2):

The way you word your question there is no way to get it 100% secure.  So what trade-offs are you willing to allow and what are you not?

What exactly are you trying to prevent?  Only one user not seeing another user's image?  Or prevent `right-click, save image as` as well?

One idea that comes to mind is combine the user's ip address with the id of the image, hash that, throw it in a cache (or use a guid as a key to look up those values).  Maybe remove it from the cache once that hash is used, therefore only allow the image to be loaded **once** by **one** ip **per page** it is supposed to be on.

You should be able to throw the mapping between a generated ID and real into the session, or `HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(cacheName, cachedValue)`  Database is probably not the best answer, they are small amounts of data, and you can set the expiration time to a small value, so unless you have millions of users at a time...

Using a Flash control to load the image would be secure in terms of can't right-click save image as.  Also probably could encrypt the stream, or split apart the image headers or something if you're worried about someone intercepting the image stream.  They could still get a url to the image, but your flash control could use special headers which would be difficult for the average user to ever figure out.

Comment: Thanks for all the ideas and challenges you've put forward. Each user will need to see multiple images per page, these images can be refreshed and shown again and again and again. 

Edit:: Accidentally pressed enter. 

Good point on the session expiry. Quite a few different things to think about there.

I have no problem with users downloading the images as they should be able to access them in the first place. My concern was anyone being able to query the handler with an ID to then retrieve an image.

Comment: From that I think I would say just generate a random number or GUID, and have that map to an Id for some amount of time.  One-way hashes of just the ID would not really work, you need something not based on the actual ID so it can't be generated logically.  Could you change the database to use a GUID as the primary key?  That would solve many of your concerns without requiring an extra layer of mapping

Comment: Unfortunately not, the database is provided by a supplier and this problem would not be deemed important enough to warrant such a large change, the ID is one of the most important unique identifiers.

I'll be researching tomorrow on cache & session expiry and which one would be the best.

Comment: Session stays until the variable is removed, or the session ends (logout, timeout). Cache has a more discreet expiration model.

Comment: This sounds largely like an authentication issue. You don't want unauthenticated users to be able to access images, and you want an authenticated user to be able to access only those images which they should have access to.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Checking to see whether the user should be able to access the resource would take a database hit, doing this n times (n being the amount of pictures for the page, on average about 14) could produce a lot of database overhead?

Comment: @Thymine Thanks for the answer, it's what I've gone with, wish I could accept 2 answers!

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost you have to know what do you consider as OK to show photo . What is your authentication parameter. Like if user is allow to see the pic when is authenticated , check the same in , ashx page before allowing it to see. Because calling inside the html as src or putting the same in browser does not make any difference for server . So you need to check some validation in case user is not at all supposed to see in any way directly or in directly

Comment: I see your point, but using the authenticated information isn't going to help in this case (unless the application takes a significant performance hit), each user could see the same photos or different ones depending upon what they do, everyone has the same role so there is no way of assigning a set of photos to a person.

With a performance hit a database lookup would need to be done to see if that user can see that person's photo or not.

Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @Robbie , see to reduce the performance hit , you can use the cache to store the user authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Store the URL and parameter in Session state and access the Session in the HttpHandler. To do this you would need to implemement the IRequiresSessionState in your handler:

[Problem with HttpHandler and session state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637189/problem-with-httphandler-and-session-state)

[Getting Session State in HttpHandlers (ASHX files)](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GettingSessionStateInHttpHandlersASHXFiles.aspx)

Comment: Session is usually not recommended due to the performance implications.

Comment: No, performance decreases as the the number of users and objects per user that are stored in session increases. Its nothing to do with the image storage.

Comment: I guess he would have to benchmark it and decide based on that?

Comment: Its usually a good idea to avoid using session when possible. Don't get me wrong, it has its place, but being a catch-all for any bit of user data is not that place.

Comment: Potentially the system could have 2,000 users (highly unlikely, but not impossible). I thought of this as a last resort.

Comment: a mapping between two 32bit ints, lets say 100 images per user, 4bytes*2*100*2000 == 160kB

Comment: A mathed example still doesn't mean its a good idea to use session in this situation. I'm not saying your answer is wrong, because it is a legitimate answer, its just not a preferable one.